# How to split a list into sublists using a predicate with Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

I am trying an idiomatic, and ideally functional way to split a list into sublists in Kotlin .

Imagine the input being `["aaa", "bbb", "", "ccc", "", "ddd", "eee", "fff"]`, I want to return `[["aaa", "bbb"], ["ccc"], ["ddd", "eee", "fff"]]` for the given predicate `string.isEmpty()`.

It is quite simple to do with a for loop and an accumulator; but I haven't found a way to write it functionally that I find readable enough.

So far my best outcome is :

```kotlin
lines.foldIndexed(Pair(listOf<List<String>>(), listOf<String>()), { idx, acc, line ->
    when {
    idx + 1 == lines.size -> {
        Pair(acc.first + listOf(acc.second + line), listOf())
    }
    line.isEmpty() -> {
        Pair(acc.first + listOf(acc.second), listOf())
    }
    else -> {
        Pair(acc.first, acc.second + line)
        }
    }
}).first
```

Essentially, I am using a `fold` with a double accumulator that keeps track of the current list and resets when the predicate is found. The list feeds into the complete result at that point. I am using a [foldIndexed](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold-indexed.html) in order to get my last list in.

Do you folks know of any better way ?

For reference, a loop version could be

```kotlin
val data = mutableListOf<String>()
var currentData = ""
for(line in lines){
    if(line.isEmpty()) {
        data.add(currentData)
        currentData = ""
    }
    else{
        currentData = "$currentData $line"
    }
}
data.add(currentData)
```

Thanks !

Comment: Someone had this exact same question last week. I don’t think there was a particularly clean way of doing it found. Your declarative loop is cleaner than anything I saw.

Comment: guessing you would have linked it if you had it, but do you have a reference to the question by any chance? Thanks!

Comment: Found it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65140871/506796

Comment: Note how similar the standard library's `CharSequence.split` is to your declarative code: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/5aaaa3881dfea4b58473dc3572be6f9ad220ea2c/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/text/Strings.kt#L1246. Functional style functions are just masks over declarative code, so I guess if it's something you use repeatedly, you need to create your own functional style functions for these cases.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! And good suggestions indeed. I try to practice FP as much as possible but I also think it should make sense. In that case I'm not quite sure yet, and was hoping for something I would have missed :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest to find splitting points (manually adding edge indices) first and then do slices:

```
val lines = listOf("aaa", "bbb", "", "ccc", "", "ddd", "eee", "fff")
val result = lines
    .flatMapIndexed { index, x ->
        when {
            index == 0 || index == lines.lastIndex -> listOf(index)
            x.isEmpty() -> listOf(index - 1, index + 1)
            else -> emptyList()
        }
    }
    .windowed(size = 2, step = 2) { (from, to) -> lines.slice(from..to) }
println(result) //[[aaa, bbb], [ccc], [ddd, eee, fff]]
```

Comment: Thanks! I like the idea indeed, it looks a bit better than carrying a pair of accumulators

Comment: How would I include the splitting points as the first element in the sublist? In my case, I want to split by headers and include every element until the next header.

Comment: @Sam, I believe you need to adjust this line: "x.isEmpty() -> listOf(index - 1, index + 1)"
If you want to include splitting point elements into the result as the first element it should become "x.isEmpty() -> listOf(index - 1, index)". If your splitting point is not an empty string, you also need to modify "x.isEmpty()" condition depending on what "header" is in your case.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a recursive version.

```
fun <T> List<T>.split(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): List<List<T>> {
    val idx = this.indexOfFirst(predicate)
    return if (idx == -1) {
        listOf(this)
    } else {
        return listOf(this.take(idx)) + this.drop(idx + 1).split(predicate)
    }
}

fun main() {
    val lines = listOf("aaa", "bbb", "", "ccc", "", "ddd", "eee", "fff")
    println(lines.split { it.isEmpty() }) // [[aaa, bbb], [ccc], [ddd, eee, fff]]
}
```

I haven't done any tests but I assume the performance isn't great, because it iterates twice over the list, once for finding the predicate matches and once for splitting the list. It's possible using `slice` or `subList` instead of `take` and `drop` gives better performance.